# Correct use of article, aside, and header tags

Tags: css, html

I have a simple page template that has a sidebar on the left and main content area on the right. Is this the correct use of the article, aside, and header tags? Also, are you suppose to attach classes/ids to html5 elements (ie. article class="example" ) or is that specifically for divs only?

Thanks

```
<article class="page">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <aside>

        <div class="col-md-3">

          <div class="sidebar">

            <h3>Sidebar Widget</h3>

              <ul>

                <li>Related Content</li>

                <li>Related Content</li>

                <li>Related Content</li>

              </ul>

          </div> <!-- /.sidebar-->

        </div> <!-- /.col-med-3 -->

      <aside>

      <div class="col-md-9">

        <header>

          <h1 class="page-title">Page Title</h1>

        </header>

          <p>Some Content</p>

      </div> <!-- /.col-med-9 -->

    </div><!-- /.row  -->

  </div><!-- /.container-->

</article><!-- /.page -->
```

Comment: In addition to being primarily opinion-based, the question cannot be meaningfully answered even as a matter of opinion, since no information is given about the nature of the actual content.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly apply a `class` and/or an `id` to HTML5 tags. Think of each tag like a `<div>`. In fact, in your CSS you should have this block, so that all HTML5 tags will behave like a `<div>`. This will help in non-HTML5 compliant browsers:

```
header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, figure {
    display: block;
}
```

I can't really comment on if you are using all of the HTML5 tags in the "correct" way since I don't know the larger scope of your project. However, it looks like you are using the `<aside>` correctly. I would use `<section>` instead of `<article>` where you used it. Here are some explanations in plain English to help you:

`<article>` - Independent, self-contained content. It should be able to stand on it's own and make sense if separated from the rest of the HTML document. The most notable potential uses are for forum/blog posts, user comments, etc.

`<aside>` - Supporting information about the larger picture of your HTML. These are mostly used in sidebars, to the left or right of the main content as part of the "supporting cast".

`<header>` - As the name suggests, this is where your heading information should go. Multiple `<header>` tags can be used throughout your HTML page (i.e. for blog post headings), but they cannot be added in `<footer>`, `<address>` or another `<header>` tag.

`<section>` - More of a "general purpose" tag, but it's used for containing large blocks of grouped content. Multiple HTML5 tags can reside inside of a `<section>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally normal to put ids and classes on any/all html elements.

Your usage of `<article>` and '' are probably too widely scoped.

The `<article>` element represents a component of a page that consists of a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is intended to be independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. [Source](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/)

The `<aside>` element represents a section of a page that consists of content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside element, and which could be considered separate from that content. [Source](http://html5doctor.com/understanding-aside/)